# 1 is not defined, optgroup in select tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I am using select2, and everything works fine until I use optgroups. The script works fine when I put the id "drink" in the select tag, but not when I put the id "drink" in the optgroup tag. Does anyone know the problem, I don't see why it doesn't work.

html:

```
    <select class="drink" name="drink" style="width: 25%">
        <optgroup label="Bieren" id="drink"></optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Sterke Bieren"></optgroup>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="collectInformation()" class="button-main">Submit</button>

    <script>
        //drinkData
        var drinkData = [
            ["Cara Pils(4,4%)", 0.044],
            ["Corona Extra(4,6%)", 0.046],
            ["Cristal(5%)", 0.05],
            ["Jupiler(5,2%)", 0.052],
            ["Maes(5,2%)", 0.052],
            ["Stella Artois(5,2%)", 0.052],
            ["Strongbow(4,5%)", 0.045]
        ];
        for (i = 0; i < drinkData.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("drink").innerHTML += "<option value='" + drinkData[i][0] + "'>" + drinkData[i][0] + "</option>";
        }
```

js:

```
function collectInformation() {
    
    //drink
    var retu;
    for (i = 0; i < drinkData.length; i++) {
        if (drinkData[i][0] == document.getElementById("drink").value) {
            retu = i;
        }
    }
    var drink = drinkData[retu][1];
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drink').select2();
});
```

I am using select2 (jQuery plugin), to have a search bar in my select options. I tried to filter my code as much as possible. I get an error in the js part of my script. It says 1 is not defined. I checked all mmy id and nothing seems wrong? Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: You put the `id` on the wrong element. It's on the `optgroup`. It needs to be on the `select` instead. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: where do you see this error? It should point to some line in your js code? which line does it point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
document.getElementById("drink").value
```

Change it to:

```
document.querySelector(".drink").value
```

or in jQuery:

```
$(".drink").val()
```

**drink** is a class and not an ID.

```js
var drinkData = [
    ["Cara Pils(4,4%)", 0.044],
    ["Corona Extra(4,6%)", 0.046],
    ["Cristal(5%)", 0.05],
    ["Jupiler(5,2%)", 0.052],
    ["Maes(5,2%)", 0.052],
    ["Stella Artois(5,2%)", 0.052],
    ["Strongbow(4,5%)", 0.045]
];
function collectInformation() {
    //drink
    var retu;
    for (i = 0; i < drinkData.length; i++) {
        if (drinkData[i][0] == document.querySelector(".drink").value) {
            retu = i;
        }
    }
    var drink = drinkData[retu][1];
    console.log(drink);
}

$('.drink').select2();


for (i = 0; i < drinkData.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("drink").innerHTML += "<option value='" + drinkData[i][0] + "'>" + drinkData[i][0] + "</option>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="drink" name="drink" style="width: 25%">
    <optgroup label="Bieren" id="drink"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Sterke Bieren"></optgroup>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="collectInformation()" class="button-main">Submit</button>
```